# How to check that any of the radio buttons was chosen using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I check that any of the radio buttons was chosen using angularjs?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an ng-model to bind to the checkbox, or radiobutton. For example:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="attachedPlansGroup" ng-model="scope.attachedPlans" ng-value="plans" /></td>
```

I put my ng-model into my $scope and called it scope.  AttachedPlans is a property under said scope.  I can then evaluate scope.attachedPlans at anytime to see if it's true or false.  The boolean indicates whether or not that radio button is selected. If you want to see a list of radiobuttons it's more like the following:

```
                                <tr ng-if="!mch.meshedObjectFlag && mch.meshedObjectTrustFlag"
                            ng-repeat="plans1 in mch.meshedObjectTrust | orderBy:orderByField1:reverseSort1  | filter: mch.planfilter1">
                            <td><input type="radio" name="attachedPlans" ng-model="mch.attachedPlans" ng-value="plans1" /></td>
                            <td>{{plans1.UnderwritingPlanCode}}</td>
                            <td>{{plans1.HOSP_CAL_YR_MAX_BENFT | currency}}</td>
                            <td align="left"> {{plans1.PREEX_DEFINITION}} {{plans1.PREEX_NO_BENFT_PERD}}</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                {{plans1.EMERGENCY_ROOM_BENFT || 0.00}}
                                {{plans1.OUTPATIENT_SURGERY_BENFT|| 0.00}}
                                {{plans1.DIAGNOSTIC_TEST_BENFT|| 0.00}}
                            </td>

                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `ng-value` which should be `true` or `false`.

A [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g8kyJ/24/)